# show/hide div on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a broadcast site, and i need hide menu when mouse not move, and show it, when mouse move. 
It works almost perfect, except one bug - menu hides only on second time if i hover it.

```js
var timedelay = 1;
var _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 500);

$('.parent').on('mousemove', showAllEvent);

function delayCheck() {
  if (timedelay == 3) {
    $('.hide').fadeOut();
    timedelay = 1;
  }
  timedelay = timedelay + 1;
}

function showAllEvent() {
  $('.hide').fadeIn();
  timedelay = 1;
  clearInterval(_delay);
  _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 500);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: black;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  if you hover me ".hide" is disappearing
  <div class='hide'>if you hover me i'm hide on second time</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want? An immidiate hide on movement?

Comment: You need to explain and/or provide a better, simpler, working example. I get erros on the code snippet and since I don't know what's suppost to do, I can't help.

Comment: is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/sg0x1g1o/ ? hide on mouseover is not needed you can use hover css

Comment: Is it me or the codepen is as bad as the question ?

Comment: Try to console.log(timedelay) and see how seldom it is ==3

Comment: @user7393973 try again

Comment: @er-han i have a broadcast site and i need hide menu when mouse not move and vise versa

Comment: @er-han just hide menu when mouse not move and show it, when mouse move. Try to check snippet.

Comment: @BogdanTushevskyi i added an answer, i hope i got it right what you espected

Comment: use $(document).on instead of   $('.parent').on

Comment: use $(document).on instead of   $('.parent').on

Comment: @trusharwidetech the same problem(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a kind of solution that feels like a hack that I implemented with the concept of `pointer-events:none` as you need to click the menu when it's displayed. So on mousemove you add a class `show` which enables the click and sets the `opacity` of the menu div to 1 and when mouse is still the div's opacity is set to 0 and pointer events are set to none.
I used `transition` property of css instead of jquery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods.

```js
var timedelay = 1;
var _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 500);

$('.parent').on('mousemove', showAllEvent);

function delayCheck() {
  if (timedelay == 3) {
    $('.hide').removeClass('show');
    timedelay = 1;
  }
  timedelay = timedelay + 1;
}

function showAllEvent() {
  $('.hide').addClass('show');
  timedelay = 1;
  clearInterval(_delay);
  _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 500);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
.show {
 opacity: 1; 
 pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  if you hover me ".hide" is disappearing
  <div class='hide'>if you hover me i'm hide on second time</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pointer-events: none; do the tricks, but unfortunately i need to click on this elements (it is a menu)

Comment: @BogdanTushevskyi I have edited my answer to suit your need that is to enable the click in the .hide div.

Comment: thnx a lot  for help, only one upgrade - add .show to .hide in html for see .hide by default

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not complete.  I fixed that (I hope).  The main issue is in your defining the event handler for mousemove.  See working example below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timedelay = 1;
        var _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 500);
        $(document).on('mousemove','.parent',function(e){
            $("span").text(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
            clearInterval(_delay);
            $('.hide').fadeIn();
            timedelay = 1;
            _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 500);
        });

        function delayCheck() {
            if (timedelay == 3) {
                $('.hide').fadeOut();
                timedelay = 1;
            }
            timedelay = timedelay + 1;
        }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hide {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            color: black;
        }

        .parent {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            border: 1px solid red;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span></span>
    <div class='parent'>
        if you hover me ".hide" is disappearing
        <div class='hide'>if you hover me i'm hide on second time</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see it run here: https://jsfiddle.net/oeu77wgv/

Comment: problem with div hiding on second time is saved

Answer (score 0):

Just set interval to 1 instead of 500, which in miliseconds, and use show() and hide() methods instead of fadeIn() and fadeOut() because they are animating in 400 miliseconds by default.

I also added `display:none` to `.hide` CSS class, now it's hidden at initial.

Now, the inner div is only visible when mouse moves on the upper div.

```js
var timedelay = 1;
var _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 1);

$('.parent').on('mousemove', showAllEvent);

function delayCheck() {
  if (timedelay == 3) {
    $('.hide').hide();
    timedelay = 1;
  }
  timedelay = timedelay + 1;
}

function showAllEvent() {
  $('.hide').show();
  timedelay = 1;
  clearInterval(_delay);
  _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 1);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: black;
  display:none;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  if you hover me ".hide" is disappearing
  <div class='hide'>if you hover me i'm hide on second time</div>
</div>
```